# How can I reaccess a terminal window that has disappeared when its deselected (focus is lost)?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

Today, suddenly after executing a terminal window and starting my script, it disappeared! there is no terminal icon on the ubuntu toolbar, and I cant access the terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]
[image]
I can create new terminal windows using dash, but I cant access them when I minimize them, once minimized they are no more accessible! 
[image]
minimized one of the terminals, its no where to be found!
[image]

I noticed its not only minimizing that makes them disappear! if I click on any program so that the focus is lost (for example If I open my browser, or sublime editor, or even navigate to one of my drives,opening a folder, etc, the terminal window will disappear !)

Comment: This is truly interesting, on the last screenshot the terminal should definitely be shown as you press Alt+Tab. Can you focus the existing terminal window, and press Alt+` (that's a backtick, typically under Escape), what does it do? It's supposed to cycle through different windows of the current application.

Comment: is it possible to have alt-tab list only the windows on the current virtual screen?

Comment: @egmont: I did that nothing happens either. there is no trace of any terminal windows. And its not only minimizing that makes them disappear!, if I click on any program so that the focus is lost (for example If I open my browser, or sublime editor, or even navigate to one of my drives, the terminal window will disappear !)

Comment: @SebastianStark: I dont know about that but its the same on the main system as well. I took the screenshots from my laptop which is connected remotely to my PC in the room.

Comment: probably inside the terminal menu, you would have enable an option like "close terminal if focus lost", but I really doubt it would have an option like that (that's would be totally stupid, just a few terminal users used only a terminal without internet or another software)

Comment: you can also try `sudo apt upgrade gnome-terminal`

Comment: sorry I meant virtual desktop

Comment: One thing to try could be to launch a tool inside gnome-terminal (e.g. `sleep 100000`), and after the terminal disappears open another one and check if this process is still running. This is to tell whether e.g. the terminal crashes.

Comment: Another idea I have: It looks you're using VNC to connect to some remote machine. `gnome-terminal` has a single process mode, and unfortunately even windows belonging to different display servers are handled by the same app. And they weren't handled quite well. Maybe the running gnome-terminal-server just gets confused which display the given window belongs to. The gnome-terminal version in Ubuntu 18.04 received some relevant changes, but I can't promise that upgrading your distro will solve this.